# Illegal assignment from List<Opportunity> to List<Integer>

Tags: salesforce

It occurs error while updating the record.recuirement is if ExpiryDate field is empty it should update the field with CloseDate. But it occurs error:Illegal assignment from `List<Opportunity>` to `List<Integer>`

```cs
If(Trigger.Isupdate){
    Exp=[Select ExpiryDate__c from Opportunity where ExpiryDate__c=Null];
    //clo=[Select CloseDate from Opportunity];
    for(opportunity Opp:Trigger.New){
        if(Opp.ExpiryDate__c=null){
            Exp.add(Opp.CloseDate);
            update Exp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit confusing about what you are trying to accomplish with this trigger code. It doesn't appear to actually do anything meaningful.

However, a couple of points:

- The error will be coming from the line: `Exp=[Select ExpiryDate__c from Opportunity where ExpiryDate__c=Null];`. I assume that `Exp` is declared as a list of integer earlier in the trigger (`List<Integer>`). Try `List<Opportunity> exp2 = [Select ExpiryDate__c from Opportunity where ExpiryDate__c=Null];`
- Why are you adding the opportunities `CloseDate` to the `Exp` collection? If `Exp` is a list of integers this will fail as CloseDate is a date. If it were a list of opportunities it would still fail.
- The line `update Exp;` should **not** be occupying within the for loop. Have a read about [bulkificaiton](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code) of triggers in Salesforce.